# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer pk field not existing on update

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, primary-key

When I try to update my model, my serializer doesn't contains pk fields.
My serializer looks like that:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pages = PageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('pk', 'tite', 'pages')
```

When I get my book from a http.get call, the datas contains the pk keys. But when I post this data with http.put method, the data catched in validated_data in my serializer doesn't contains the pk fields. DO I have to define this pk fied on each serializer? I though DRF 3 should do it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to update the `pk` anyway. By default, it's read-only so you won't have it for write operations.
If you really require it, mark it as read-write.

Comment: Is there another way to proceed if I want to udpdate nested fields?

Comment: Why would there be ? It's very straight forward using [extra_kwargs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) on the nested serializer.

Comment: yeah , we don't want update pk, but we may want read pk , knows what is the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

you may find pk in self.instance, also id and all other values of object that we are updating

```
if self.instance:
   pk = self.instance.pk
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicity declare the field in the serializer:

```py
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Or if that is a nested serializer, user `required=False` so you can also add new objects:

```py
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```